# How to convert map(key,struct) to map(key,caseclass) in spark scala dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have dataframe schema -

resultDF.printSchema

```
 |-- SKU_ID_MAP: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SKU_IMAGE_MAP: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: struct (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- image_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- image_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- image_path: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to create a final dataframe like this from above DF.

```
   case class Devicesku2 (
     sku_id : String,
     sku_images: Map[String, ImageInfo2]
   )

   resultDF.map(
      row => Devicesku2(
                row.getAs[String]("SKU_ID"),
                row.getAs[Map]("SKU_IMAGE_MAP")
   ).toDF
```

In above row.getAs[Map] is giving compile time error as value is struct type.

Can someone help on this?
Thanks,

`

Comment: Try `row.getAs[Map[String, ImageInfo2]]("SKU_IMAGE_MAP")`

Comment: case class ImageInfo2 is not defined in the example

Comment: case class ImageInfo2 (
   
    image_id : String,
    image_name : String,
    image_path : String   
 
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you rename your `case class`'s elements to:

```
case class Devicesku2 (
  sku_id_map: String,
  sku_image_map: Map[String, ImageInfo2]
)
```

You can just use

```
resultDF.as[Devicesku2]
```

Otherwise, as mentioned in Aluan Haddad's comment, you'll need

```
row.getAs[Map[String, ImageInfo2]]("SKU_IMAGE_MAP")
```

Comment: Thanks. I am able to create DF with row.getAs[Map[String, ImageInfo2]]("SKU_IMAGE_MAP").                                                                                                                 output - |sku130416|Map(null -> [null,null,null]) -  for few records.                i want to replace map with null if it's key is null else map. How can we do this on DF?

Comment: DF.printSchema |                                                                                   
 -- sku_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sku_images: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: struct (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- image_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- image_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- image_path: string (nullable = true)

Comment: You should ask that as a seperate question. It's not related to this thread and is a completely different problem altogether.